# 0 value not working when import excel sheet for if condition in laravel excel

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

Excel file as below

```
Id |   pro name | status 
1  |   test.          | 0
```

- Laravel 5.6
- PHP 7.2
- Maatwebsite/excel 2.*

Below my Laravel code

```
$data = Excel::load($path)->get();
```

if print `$data` then its show me `0`.

```
echo $data[0]->status; // output:0

if($data[0]->status === ""){
    echo "Status field required"; exit;
}
if($data[0]->status === 0 || $data[0]->status === 1){
    echo "successfully";exit;
}else{
    echo "status format 0 or 1 required"; exit;
}
```

if I set `0` value in the status column then also print `Status field required`.
if I set `(int)$data[0]->status` then `Null` value show as `0`.so how can i solve this issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel sheet import value always return in string format so you try below code

```
$status = $data[0]->status;
if(is_null($status)){
    echo "Status field required";exit;
}else{
    $status = (int)$status;
}
if($status === 0 || $status === 1){
    echo "successfully";exit;
}else{
    echo "status format 0 or 1 required"; exit;
}
```